# Isomorphism In Ring Theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $R$ be a ring with unity. Then show that: $\dfrac{R[x]}{\langle x \rangle}\cong R$.

I have defined a homomorphism : $\phi:\mathbb R[x]\to \mathbb R$ such that $\phi( a_0+a_1x+\cdots)=a_0$.

Further I got $\ker(\phi) = \{f(x) \in R[x] \mid \phi(f(x)) = 0 \}$ which is

$\ker(\phi) = \{xg(x) \in R[x] \mid g(x) \in R[x]\}$.

My question is how $\langle x \rangle = \{xg(x) \in R[x] \mid g(x) \in R[x]\}$.

Comment: I have defined a homomorphism from $R[x]$ to R by a function that maps a polynomial from $R[x]$ to its constant term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let 
\begin{align*}
\Phi:R[X]&\longrightarrow R\\
p(X)&\longmapsto p(0).
\end{align*}
I let you prove that it's a ring morphism. The surjectivity is clear. Now, as you said, $\ker(Phi)=\{p(X)\in R[X]\mid p(0)=0\}.$

Observe that $$p(X)=a_0+a_1X+...+a_nX^n\in \ker(Phi)\iff p(X)=a_1X+...+a_nX^n=X(a_1+...+a_nX^n)\iff \exists g(X)\in R[X]\mid p(X)=Xg(X)\in \left<X\right>.$$

Therefore, $$\ker(Phi)=\left<X\right>.$$